# JavaScript OO issue when accessing instance methods

Tags: javascript, oop, this, prototype-programming

I've used a few tutorials on OOP in JavaScript. It seemed to go well, until I met the following...

```
Result of expression 'this.prepareFrame' [undefined] is not a function.
```

Ok. I'm using `prototype` and make use of the `this` keyword.

See my `app.js` page here...

```
// Plain "main" function called by the html page, like <script>main()</script>. This works nicely:

    function main() {
    engine = new AbstractEngine();
    engine.init();
    }

// Next creates a new instance of my AbstractEngine class. Seems to work so far:

    function AbstractEngine() {}

// The init() method we called is defined afterwards:

    AbstractEngine.prototype.init = function() {
    this.initLoop();
    }

// remark: I'm using "this", and according to the debugger, "this" refers to the AbstractEngine we made an instance of.

// Next, we define the initLoop method:

    AbstractEngine.prototype.initLoop = function() {
    setInterval(this.tick, 1000 / 30);
    }

// Fine, everything works fine so far. Now get to define the "tick" method:

    AbstractEngine.prototype.tick = function() {
    this.prepareFrame();
    this.update();
    }

// Ok, we're in trouble. The error message is output to the console and I don't understand why... The prepareFrame() and update() methods are defined right afterwards:

    AbstractEngine.prototype.update = function() {
    console.log('updating!');
    }

    AbstractEngine.prototype.prepareFrame = function() {
    console.log('preparing frame');
    }

// I read my code twice, but didn't find beginner's mistakes like typo or whatever. But well, cosnider I'm a beginner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
setInterval(this.tick, 1000 / 30);
```

Should be:

```
var that = this;
setInterval(function () { that.tick(); }, 1000 / 30);
```

or alternately:

```
setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000 / 30);
```

---

**Explanation:** when you pass simply `this.tick`, that is the same as doing the following:

```
var temp = this.tick;
setInterval(temp, 1000 / 30);
```

But now, when `temp` is called, JavaScript doesn't know what the `this` pointer should be; that information gets lost, and it ends up getting bound to the global object (`window`), or to `null` if you are in strict mode.

So you need to somehow ensure that `this.tick` is called as a method with the appropriate `this` pointer. There are two ways to do this:

1. By wrapping it in a closure that captures `var that = this`, you can properly call `that.tick` as a method on the original `this` pointer.
2. Or by `bind()`ing the `this.tick` function to `this`, you ensure it is called as a method with the appropriate `this` every time: in other words, you could even do `var temp = this.tick.bind(this)` and `setInterval(temp, 1000 / 30)`.

Note that `bind` is not available in older browsers (notably IE <= 8 and all Safaris so far up to and including 5.1), in which case you'd need something like [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).

Comment: Your suggested solution will not work as `this` changes meaning in your anonymous function which was passed to `setInterval`.  See Matt's answer.

Comment: Hey thanks for the working answer and explanation. I'll now digest the information ;) Thanks!

Comment: Hmm...not sure what happened there...either there was another answer posted which has since been deleted and I accidentally commented on yours, or I totally misread your answer. I could have sworn I saw a suggested solution of `setInterval( function(){ this.tick(); }, 100/30 );`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the definition of `initLoop` to be the following:

```
AbstractEngine.prototype.initLoop = function() {
    var that = this;

    setInterval(function () {
        that.tick();
    }, 1000 / 30);
}
```

This is because the resolution of `this` is delayed until execution time and when the interval is executed, `this` points to `window`, rather than your instance of `AbstractEngine`.

By wrapping the call to `tick` in an anonymous function, we create a closure which allows us to capture `that` (which we set to `this`). By calling the **method** `tick` on the **instance** that (which is the *old* this), we can restore the value of "this").

Comment: I had the answer all drafted up, but you post before  could even paste it into the answer box. :)